# Check if a symbol is present in a dll

Tags: c++, dll

I've built a opensource project ([OpenDDS](http://opendds.org/)), using Visual Studio 2015. It creates a lot of libraries.

I want to use one of its class in one of my project, but I don't find in the documentation the name of the dll in which I can find the corresponding symbol.

Is there a way, given a class name, to find a .dll that contains it? Or is possible to check if a given library has a specific symbol without building a project for finding linker errors?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30e78zd0.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Duplicating information from MSDN is not useful.